# how to add column in material-table with help of Component Overriding?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I Want to use material-table to setup table where the last row will be used to show the calculated total of one column. as per the **material-table** doc, I guess I can use **Component Overriding** in **Cell** or **Row**.

Comment: Is there anything you tried yet ?